# Error: 'shuffle' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, std

Using C++17, whenever I try to use `std::shuffle`, I get the error:

> 'error: 'shuffle' is not a member of 'std''

I'm using the Eclipse C++ IDE and MinGW 8.2 and can use other functions such as mt19937, string, etc perfectly fine. Here's the code where it keeps acting up:

```
#include "MyHeader.h"
#include <random>
using namespace std;

void generateDictionary() {
    int initialAlphabet[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        initialAlphabet[i] = i;
    }

    std::mt19937 randomSeed(std::random_device{}());
    std::shuffle(initialAlphabet, initialAlphabet+26, randomSeed);
}
```

Comment: `std::shuffle()` is declared in `<algorithm>`, which you are missing an `#include` for

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. That was the problem, I spent ~1 hr trying to trouble shoot it (and other things), only to now realize that I missed <algorithm> on the c++ docs!

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry about the off-topic question, but when the resolving answer is given in the comments, what is a good course of action?

Comment: @Enthus3d, Giving a hint that it should be an answer, answering the question yourself, or voting to close the question if it should be closed (waiting for others to do so at lower rep). It depends on the circumstances. One reason for comment answers is that the author would feel obliged to put in a lot more effort for an actual answer or they wouldn't feel proud enough of their answer that they want reputation from it. I think making it a community answer solves both of those well enough. There's probably a topic or two about this on meta already.

Comment: Obligated* not obliged, in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::shuffle comes from algorithm

Add

```
#include <algorithm>
```

and that should fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

`std::shuffle` is included in `<algorithm>`

I also had a headache when trying to use random_shuffle and realized it became deprecated.